Pip install aicspylibczi Failure
I am trying to read a czi file in python, and to do so I am using the aicsimageio library. however, it needs an addiaitonal aicspylibczi library. However, when I am trying to install it, I am met with this error. I am unable to find out how to reolve this issue. Could someone please help me out? Thanks
pip install aicspylibczi


Collecting aicspylibczi
  Using cached aicspylibczi-3.1.2.tar.gz (7.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.1 in c:\users\kvs62\pycharmprojects\epibolyseg\.venv\lib\site-packages (from aicspylibczi) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: aicspylibczi
  Building wheel for aicspylibczi (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aicspylibczi (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aicspylibczi
      copying aicspylibczi\CziFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aicspylibczi
      copying aicspylibczi\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aicspylibczi
      copying aicspylibczi\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aicspylibczi
      copying aicspylibczi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aicspylibczi
      running egg_info
      writing aicspylibczi.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aicspylibczi.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aicspylibczi.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aicspylibczi.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aicspylibczi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pxi' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pyd' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.so' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.d' under directory 'c_tests'
      warning: no files found matching '*.hpp' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pxi' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pyd' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.so' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      warning: no files found matching '*.d' under directory '_aicspylibczi'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'aicspylibczi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aicspylibczi
Failed to build aicspylibczi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aicspylibczi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects



I was facing the same problem.
I fixed it by using a Python version under 3.10.
